# How does rails activerecord where clause accepts dynamic parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, methods, dynamic

In ruby web define parameters for a method.

```
def para_check(para1, para2, para3 .... )

end
```

How does activerecord `.where` is defined so that it accepts dynamic parameters ?

I went though few blogs/websites but could not find useful resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby you can prefix the parameter with a splat (`*`) to define methods that accept any number of positional arguments:

```
def foo(*x)
  x
end

foo(1,2,3) == [1,2,3] # true
```

This is also known as a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#:~:targetText=In%20mathematics%20and%20in%20computer,neologism%2C%20dating%20back%20to%201936.). As you can see this creates a array from the list of arguments.

You can also combine numbered and positional arguments and a splat:

```
foo(bar, *args)
  [bar, args]
end

foo(1, 'a', 'b') == [1, ['a','b']] # true
```

This makes the method require one argument but allows an infinate number of arguments.

The `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where` method accepts both positional and keyword arguments:

```
where('foo = :x OR bar = :y', x: 1, x: 2)
```

Starting with Ruby 2.0 you can do this with:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs)
  [args, kwargs]
end

foo(1, 2, 3, bar: 'baz') == [[1, 2, 3], { bar: 'baz' }] ## true
```

Previously you had to use various hacky solutions with array parameters and and optional hash parameter. You can still find these in the Rails source code and in a lot of other code written before Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. For starters you could accept a hash or array as parameter.

So if you expect a `Hash`, that is what `where` does, you can just write

```
def para_check(params) 
  params.each do |param_name, param_value|
    # do something with the params
  end 
end
```

and then you can write:

```
para_check(para1: "X", para2: "Y", para5: "Z")
```

An alternative, in this case maybe, if you need to specify a list/array of parameters, you can also define your method as follows:

```
def para_check(*params)
  params.each do |param_name| 
    # do something with param_name
  end
end
```

(the '*'-operator is called the splat-operator)

and then you call your method as follows

```
para_check(:para1, :para2, :para4)
```